# What branch am I on now?

Tags: git

I'm using `git`. When I run `git status`, it shows the output below. My question is, what branch am I on?

```
d:\2016_Project\toyota\tpm>git status                                                                                                
HEAD detached from 42376c1                                                                                                           
nothing to commit, working directory clean                                                                                           

d:\2016_Project\toyota\tpm>git log --all --oneline
5d4239f done basic styling                                                                                                           
42376c1 done notif on reminder page                                                                                                  
d673796 done reminder page                                                                                                           
514aba8 done prospek task                                                                                                            
e88ff91 done update prospek profil & task                                                                                            
289654b add fontawesome                                                                                                              
377c594 done basic prospek profile                                                                                                   
d59022c add prospek task                                                                                                             
:
```

Update#1
Here is when I list my branch. Which branch that have my last changed version?

```
d:\2016_Project\toyota\tpm>git branch                                                                                                
* (detached from 42376c1)                                                                                                            
  add-customer-profile                                                                                                               
  master
```

Comment: Well, which branch were you working on more recently? If you're the only one working on the project, it's _most likely_ that it's `add-customer-profile`, but there's no way to tell from the information you've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not currently on a branch. Your `git` is currently in what is known as "detached HEAD" mode, in which your HEAD (the current most recent commit) is pointing to an arbitrary commit in your history rather than the tip of a specific branch. You most likely reached this state by doing `git checkout <commit-id>`, and can return to the tip of a branch of your choosing by doing `git checkout <branch-name>`.

Comment: please see my update#1 for list of all branch. Which branch that have my last changed version?

Comment: many thanks @sebastian, there is no branch that have the latest version of my files. so on current pointer, i just create a new branch that have my last version of changed files. thanks again.